# Find the length of the segment of the straight line connecting the midpoints of its diagonals.

Tags: geometry

The bases of a trapezoid are $a,b$ long.Find the length of the segment of the straight line connecting the midpoints of its diagonals.

---

I dont know how to start this question.Please give me some hints.The answer given is $\frac{1}{2}|a-b|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the parallels horizontal. Then one parallel edge is $[u,u+a]$ on some level $y=m+{h\over2}$, and the other parallel edge is $[v,v+b]$ on the level $y=m-{h\over2}$, whereby $h$ denotes the height of the trapezoid. Now compute the midpoints of the two diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is just a mean geometry sending a line of length $a$ to one of $-b$, so the signed length is $\frac{1}{2}(a-b)$, and unsigned is $\frac{1}{2}\arrowvert a-b\arrowvert$, as desired.

Comment: I did not understand your method.